# iframe call causing a "Blocked a frame with origin…" error

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, iframe

I'm calling an iframe from a page that is on a subdomain… so subdomain.mydomain.com is calling an iframe on a page on mydomain.com. It works fine in FF on both PC and Mac, but will not display on IE and will throw an error on Safari 6.1:

Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a frame with origin "http://sudobmain.mydomain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I've read all of the CORS documentation.

I've added this to .htaccess file as well:

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://mydomain.com/"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

I'm sure I'm missing something - just not sure what it might be.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is due to security policies not possible.
"Protocols, domains, and ports must match." - domains. Usually this includes subdomains.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly the issue. I'm wondering if there's a way around it.